# Making sure my desktop is locked when it goes into sleep mode

Tags: linux, laptop, security, sleep, lock

Is there a way to install some kind of a hook that'd make sure `xlock` or a similar program is called before my laptop goes to sleep, regardless of the origin of the request (calling `pm-suspend` from a script, or just closing the lid etc.) and window manager I'm currently using?

(I'm currently using Debian Linux, but I suppose there will be a distribution-agnostic solution.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as the kernel does not provide any sort of "going to sleep" signal before freezing all processes, there is no distribution-agnostic way to detect it.

That said, *pretty much all* suspend requests – including lid-close – tend to go through a few userspace APIs: eventually, they either call systemd-logind's `Suspend()` function via D-Bus, or spawn the `pm-suspend` command. Both have various kinds of "hooks" which can be used for this.

(Note that no matter what you do, a direct `echo mem > /sys/power/state` remains nearly invisible to userspace, short of watching for sudden clock jumps...)

#### So, if you use *systemd* as init:

1. Install `xss-lock` and make your desktop environment start it on login (via `~/.xinitrc`, via `~/.config/autostart/`, or via whatever):

   ```
   xss-lock xlock &
   ```

   This will handle systemd's pre-suspend notifications, as well as manual `loginctl lock-sessions` calls should you ever need those.
2. Create a pm-utils hook script at `/etc/pm/sleep.d/50lock`:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   loginctl lock-sessions
   ```

   (Don't forget to `chmod +x`.) You don't need this for regular systemd suspend, but it will send out a notification to xss-lock whenever you manually run `pm-suspend`.

#### If you're using another init system:

If you're using `pm-suspend`, I suppose you could run `xlock` *directly* from the pm/sleep.d hook script. That would require you to also directly set `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` environment variables, which is kinda awful since they can vary from boot to boot (although some people hardcode `:0` there...)

Overall, in that situation, desktop-environment-specific methods might work better.